# IOS10 app's widgets don't appear when an user open the app, but them can be clicked

Tags: ios, swift

I've upload my app(develop by Swift3) into Apple App Store, but there's an user give me a feedback message that when she downloaded my app from Apple App Store and opened it. After pushing the first viewcontroller(I've init a viewcontroller plastereding with an UIImageView. ps:like LaunchScreen) into the navigationController, All widgets which are in the second viewcontroller(My logincontroller,there some UITextFileds and UIButton) didn't show in the screen but she can also click them(they were all right but couldn't appear).

PS:This user can not find my app in her iPhone's settings too.

Comment: Check `alphaValue`, maybe it's set to 0.

Comment: But my app runs normally in other users' iPhones...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274921/app-settings-are-missing-in-the-settings-app you can check this for missing app in settings. What's her iOS version?

Comment: I've browsed this website, and my user's IOS version is 10.3.3. The man just simply opened multitasking view (double-click Home), and ejected the Settings app. According to it, I can't also figure out what's wrong with my app...